# how to compress/ decompress a folder in asp.net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net 4.0 framework, I am generating pdf files from my page and storing those pdf files in a folder, in my application. now the  size of application is becoming too large, so I want to compress that pdf file's folder and download that folder. please suggest me how to compress/ decompress a folder in c#.

Comment: No idea what you're asking. You want to enable Folder Compression to lessen the "size of your application"? Or you want to allow users to download a ZIP archive with PDF files your application has generated?

Comment: what did you try? which errors did you get? please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

One way to compress the datavolume is to generate a .zip folder from that directory:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you take your .pdf folder, zip it and extract it somewhere else using

```
CompressionLevel.Fastest, true
```